# Multiline echo PHP not working

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I bought this book that told me to download XAMPP and installed it on my laptop. It installed fine but when I started coding, I noticed the multiline echo doesn't work. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling a later version, still it doesn't work. And I tried to install WAMP from another website and still it doesn't work. 
My code looks like this

```
<?php
  $author = "Bill Gates";

  $text = "Measuring programming progress by lines of code is like
  Measuring aircraft building progress by weight.

  - $author.";
echo $text;
?>
```

All I get is this in single line.

Normal people believe that if it ain’t broke, don’t fix it. Engineers believe that if it ain’t broke, it doesn’t have enough features yet. - Scott Adams.

I'm using Windows 7. Anybody who has an idea what's wrong, please do reply.

Comment: You're looking at this through a Web Browser, right? So HTML applies, right? So you need to use `<br />` for a new line in HTML

Comment: I even tried using the \n to start new line but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Your code works fine: https://3v4l.org/pfEcb

Comment: Though I can't explain why you get a Scott Adams quote when your PHP is supposed to be displaying a Bill Gates quote

Comment: You can also wrap `<pre>...</pre>` tags around it but it also applies formatting in most browsers.

Comment: When you view this in your browser, use the "view source" option in the browser.  You'll see the line breaks there.

Comment: You can use PHP's [nl2br()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function to convert new line ("\n") to an HTML `<br />` break

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
echo $text;
```

use

```
echo nl2br($text);
```

See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 0):

Here HTML tag `<br />` can help you:

```
<?php
      $author = "Bill Gates";

      $text = "Measuring programming progress by lines of code is like
      Measuring aircraft building progress by weight.
        <br /><br />
      - $author.";
    echo $text;
    ?>
```

Here you can see examples: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Comment: Care to explain *why* this is a solution to their problem?